# My wordpress website gets redirected to another website on Desktop browser but works fine on mobile

Tags: wordpress, redirect

My website [www.techspurt.net](http://www.techspurt.net) gets redirected to a spam website when i try to open it from desktop and I am not even able to open it's wp admin panel either where as it works perfectly fine when I try to access it via my mobile phone. I scanned my site via Wordfence and disabled all my plugins and even updated them as well but it did no good. Kindly help me out!

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately your site has been infected with malware (see [Sucuri's malware scan results](https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/www.techspurt.net)). Maybe this [FAQ](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/faq-my-site-was-hacked/) from the WordPress team can help you out. Good luck!